# Facebook C# SDK and OAuth Server-side flow in ASP.NET 4

Tags: silverlight-4.0, facebook-c#-sdk, asp.net-4.0, server-side, oauth-2.0

I am working on a Silverlight 4 browser app from which I managed to succeed in complete the client-side flow authentication process. I've decided to better move to the server-side flow but, though I provide the same redirect_uri as I provided in the client-side flow once I get the "code" from Facebook, I am not getting automatically redirected to the uri I've set (I do get the access_token if I retrieve the response as string)

I am making the requests from an .aspx page:

```
            var client = new WebClient();
            client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            var encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();


            var inputs = new NameValueCollection
                                 {
                                     {"client_id", appId},
                                     {"redirect_uri", "http://localhost:57613/CallbackForm.aspx"},
                                     {"client_secret", "XXXXX"},
                                     {"code", Code}
                                 };

            var result = encoding.GetChars(client.UploadValues("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token", inputs));
            string asciiString = new string(result);
```

But now the problem is that I need my page to be redirected with the access_token passed by URL in order to get my Silverlight control reloaded as well (it is hosted in the same .aspx page where I have this code snippet), because I need the silverlight content being loaded again to complete the only way I know to get the access token from the .aspx page (calling a javascript function from silverlight). Could somebody help me and explain how can I get the page redirected when querying for the access_token, or how can I pass the access_token to the silverlight control in a different way?

Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

There has been a change in Facebook behavior regarding the structure of the query string. This is discussed in http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/discussions/261528. This link discussed a change to the auth procedure which should fix your issue. My code uses WPF and not Silverlight; I'm not sure whether the same issue applies to the Silverlight control.

Also see [Does Facebook Client-Side Flow still give out access tokens?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6450083/does-facebook-client-side-flow-still-give-out-access-tokens) and [SL4 Facebook application no longer retrieves access_token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6286807/sl4-facebook-application-no-longer-retrieves-access-token).

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at those posts