# Webbrowser not firing events when you click links after navigating to a page

Tags: wpf, browser

I'm using a webbrowser(System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser; actually it is a frame, but AFAIK it's the same control).

When I navigate through C# as in:

```
browser.Navigate(loginUrl, "bla", new byte[0], "");
```

The "Navigated" event is fired. But once I'm at this page and I click on a link and navigate to somewhere else, I receive no new "Navigated" events. Is there anything I can do about it?

Thanks.

Solution:
[WPF WebBrowser - detecting redirects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6487261/wpf-webbrowser-detecting-redirects/6592884#6592884)

Comment: Please [vote to close your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/view-close-votes) as duplicates of that other question, rather than simply stamping [SOLVED].

Comment: @BoltClock done