# WPF WebBrowser control - "Navigating" event not firing

Tags: c#, wpf, webbrowser-control

I have a simple application that uses the WPF web browser:

```
<WebBrowser x:Name="browserMovieLinks" Navigating="browserMovieLinks_Navigating"/>
```

and the event handler in codebehind:

```
private void browserMovieLinks_Navigating(object sender, NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
        {
    //do whatever
}
```

For the past couple of years, this has worked flawlessly: when the user clicked a link in the page shown by the WebBrowser control, the Navigating event always fired.

However, I noticed that lately (don't know when or why unfortunately) this has stopped working. Don't know if it's because I'm on a different machine or if something changed in the .NET libraries or in the IE implementation underneath the WebBrowser control, but now the event does not fire anymore.

Any clues as to what is going on?

**NOTE: before you point it out, I know there are other similar questions on SO (example: [Webbrowser not firing events when you click links after navigating to a page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7421452/300741)) but NONE of them give a proper solution. They all suggest to use a different 3rd party component or don't have a satisfactory answer whatsoever, so I'm opening this one in the hope of getting a PROPER answer to this question.**

Comment: looks like you didn't get an answer.  I came here with the same question. My company won't let me use 3rd party components. My issue is that Navigating, Navigated, and LoadCompleted only fire when you use the Navigate(url) method.  But if navigation occurs due to user interaction with the browser, the events don't get fired.  Hosting a Windows.Forms.WebBrowser works, but the Tab, Ctrl-C, Ctrl-V don't work and users complain.  So I really need to find a solution.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? I'm seeing a similar issue where sometimes I get the Navigated event firing without the Navigating event occuring.

Comment: It seems it was some problem at system level in my case, the embedded system IE engine was screwed, it behaved weirdly even in other system applications... never found out the root cause tho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to close this question: in my case it was some kind of problem at system level, IE was behaving strangely in other scenarios too. On a new Windows installation it started working again.

Answer (score 3):

(One caveat, I had this issue in WinForms with the WebBrowser control, so it may not be exactly the same as in WPF.)

What do your links look like? I had a similar issue that was caused by the target parameter in the anchor link being set to _blank.

So:

```
<a href="https://example.com" target="_blank">
```

would correctly open the link in another window, but wouldn't fire any navigation events since the browser itself wasn't navigating anywhere. My solution was to remove the target parameter:

```
<a href="https://example.com">
```

which then caused the navigation event to occur for the browser.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that wasn't the problem in my case, there was something weird going on at system level with IE, formatting and reinstalling Windows fixed it. Sorry for not closing the question sooner, I had forgotten about it 